# What permissions are needed to create User Defined Database role

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance

**Question**: If you are not a db_owner or a sysadmin, what minimal permissions are needed to perform the following tasks:

1. Create user defined database role, say, `MyDbRole`
2. List item all users inside `db_ddladmin` role
3. Move the users from db_ddladmin` role to MyDbRole
4. Assign following permissions to MyDbRole: CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP any table, stored procedure, function

Comment: Hello, @nam. Have you checked the documentation? It should give you that info.

Comment: @Ronaldo I did check documentation, and could not find the permission info. Did not even find a Microsoft doc on User Defined Database role. This [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+user+defined+database+role&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS998US998&oq=sql+server+use&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j0i512l6.13711j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has articles from many authors but none of them talk about what permissions are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to verify the minimal needed privileges for a given task is to check the documentation since it normally contains a section related to permissions. So, for example, in order to understand the permissions to perform the item 1 of your question, you should verify the [CREATE ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) doc. More specifically, you should read the [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) section:

> ### Permissions
>
> Requires **CREATE ROLE** permission on the database or membership in
> the **db_securityadmin** fixed database role. [...]

Like that you verify the documentation for each step of your request.

---

**Related to your request:**

[sys.database_role_members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-role-members-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[GRANT Database Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: db_securityadmin role did the trick (thank you). +1.

Comment: I have a similar security question posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/317668/56185) - in case you have a suggestion or a possible solution