# How to add Azure AD user to a Database role

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-sql-server

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error shown below. The user running the code below is a member of `db_securityadmin` database role:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [myDomainName.com\Juan]
```

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Cannot add the principal 'myDomainName.com\Juan', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

**Remark**: User `Juan@myDomainName.com` does exist and can login to his laptop as `Juan@myDomainName.com`. The following code also gives the same error:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [Juan@myDomainName.com]
```

Ref: [Add a member to a fixed server role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/join-a-role?view=sql-server-ver16#to-add-a-member-to-a-fixed-server-role-1)

Comment: "User Juan@myDomainName.com does exists and can login to his laptop as Juan@myDomainName.com." can that user login to SQL Server using SSMS?

Comment: @Ronaldo Your comment helped me resolved the issue (thank you). `Juan@myDomainName.com` exists in the `Security\logins` folder of SQL Managed Instance. But, we missed the following step in current db first: `CREATE USER [Juan@myDomainName.com] FROM LOGIN [Juan@myDomainName.com]`. Afterwards, the issue was resolved. For benefits of other users, if you like, you can explain the process in a bit more details - and I'll mark it as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making a user member of [Server-level roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16) or [Database-level roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16) it is important to make sure the login/user is already among the [Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) listed on the instance and database.

1. Check if the `Juan@myDomainName.com` login (or a Windows group of
   which it is a member) exists on the instance: `Security > Logins`.
   If it's not, run a [CREATE
   LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
   command;
2. Check if there's a user created on the database associated to that
   login: `Databases > YouDataBase > Security > Users`. If you can't
   find one, create it with the  [CREATE
   USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
   command.

A very practical way to verify that in your case is to test if `Juan@myDomainName.com` can login and navigate to the database you'll be giving permissions using SSMS.